# Dynamic type matching in method argument

Tags: c++, oop, derived-class, visitor-pattern

I have base class Shape and some subclasses inherited from it like Circle, Rectangle, AlignedRectangle, ConvexPolygon, ConcavePolygon etc. I want each of such classes to have method
`bool intersect(Shape &other);`
which checks if two shapes intersect. I want to have different implementations of such method for different pairs of classes, because some intersections can be computed much faster than brute-force approach.
I want such method so I can intersect two Shape* pointers without caring about what types are actually inside.

Here is my current approach.

```
class Circle;
class Rect;

class Shape {
 public:
    Shape() {}

    virtual bool intersect(Shape &a) = 0;
    virtual bool intersect_circle(Circle &a) = 0;
    virtual bool intersect_rect(Rect &a) = 0;
};

class Circle : public Shape {
 public:
    Circle() {}
    virtual bool intersect(Shape &a);
    virtual bool intersect_circle(Circle &a);
    virtual bool intersect_rect(Rect &a);
};

class Rect : public Shape {
 public:
    Rect() {}
    virtual bool intersect(Shape &a);
    virtual bool intersect_circle(Circle &a);
    virtual bool intersect_rect(Rect &a);
};

bool Circle::intersect(Shape &a) {
    a.intersect_circle(*this);
}

bool Circle::intersect_circle(Circle &a) {
    cout << "Circle::intersect_circle" << endl;
}

bool Circle::intersect_rect(Rect &a) {
    cout << "Circle::intersect_rect" << endl;
}

bool Rect::intersect(Shape &a) {
    a.intersect_rect(*this);
}

bool Rect::intersect_circle(Circle &a) {
    cout << "Rect::intersect_circle" << endl;
}

bool Rect::intersect_rect(Rect &a) {
    cout << "Rect::intersect_rect" << endl;
}
```

Is there some other, 'better' way to do it? 
It may be fine for intersection of two shapes, but what if I wanted to have method that have two or more arguments that can have any type? This is extension for 3 classes case:

```
void Circle::some_stuff(Shape &a, Shape &b) {
    a.some_stuff_circle(*this, b);
}

void OtherClass::some_stuff_circle(Circle &a, Shape &b) {
    b.some_stuff_circle_other_class(a, *this);
}

void AnotherClass::some_stuff_circle_other_class(Circle &a, OtherClass &b) {
    //do things here
}
```

There is gonna be so much redundant code. I may be missing something fundamental though.

Comment: You've reinvented the visitor pattern.  BTW, multiple argument dynamic dispatch is something Bjarne's written about, so it may appear in standard C++ in the future.  You may like to search on "multimethods in C++"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variant type for this. Here's one possible solution using my [Polyvar](https://github.com/badair/polyvar) header. It isn't the prettiest nor the most flexible solution, but it does allow you to selectively overload `intersect` and still have dynamically polymorphic behavior. I think it's as good as you're going to get in C++.

*Note: Polyvar depends on Boost.Variant, if you use it as-is. Feel free to tweak the macros if you want to use std::variant or some other variant implementation.*

```
#include "polyvar.hpp"
#include <iostream>

// Define a variant template with a self-visiting member
// function named `intersect`. We'll use this to emulate a base class
DEFINE_POLYVAR(ShapeVariant, (intersect));

class Circle {

 public:

    Circle() {}

    template<typename T>
    bool intersect(T &a) {
        std::cout << "Circle to ???\n";
        auto your_implementation = false;
        return your_implementation;
    }
    bool intersect(Circle &a) {
        std::cout << "Circle to Circle\n";
        auto your_implementation = false;
        return your_implementation;
    }

    bool intersect(class Rect &a) {
        std::cout << "Circle to Rect\n";
        auto your_implementation = false;
        return your_implementation;
    }
};

class Rect {

 public:

    Rect(){}

    template<typename T>
    bool intersect(T &a) {
        std::cout << "Rect to ???\n";
        auto your_implementation = false;
        return your_implementation;
    }
    bool intersect(Circle &a) {
        std::cout << "Rect to Circle\n";
        auto your_implementation = false;
        return your_implementation;
    }

    bool intersect(Rect &a) {
        std::cout << "Rect to Rect\n";
        auto your_implementation = false;
        return your_implementation;
    }
};

class Triangle {

 public:

    Triangle(){}

    template<typename T>
    bool intersect(T &a) {
        std::cout << "Triangle to ???\n";
        auto your_implementation = false;
        return your_implementation;
    }

    bool intersect(Triangle &a) {
        std::cout << "Triangle to Triangle\n";
        auto your_implementation = false;
        return your_implementation;
    }
};

using Shape = ShapeVariant<Circle, Rect, Triangle /*, etc */>;

// Polyvar adds one level of visitation, but we must add another.
bool intersect(Shape& s1, Shape& s2) {

    auto visitor = [&s1](auto& s2) {
        return s1.intersect(s2);
    };

    return boost::apply_visitor(visitor, s2);
}

int main () {

    Shape s1 = Circle{};
    Shape s2 = Rect{};
    Shape s3 = Triangle{};

    intersect(s1, s2);
    intersect(s2, s1);
    intersect(s1, s3);
    intersect(s3, s2);
    intersect(s1, s1);
    intersect(s2, s2);
    intersect(s3, s3);
}
```

Output:

Circle to Rect

Rect to Circle

Circle to ???

Triangle to ???

Circle to Circle

Rect to Rect

Triangle to Triangle

---

[Live example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/L2PaL4AXrS9GLieK)

---

See also - multiple dispatch:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch)
- [A Polyglot's Guide to Multiple Dispatch](https://dzone.com/articles/a-polyglots-guide-to-multiple-dispatch)

---

By the way, don't forget to make your code `const`-correct.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid repetition I came up with this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

class Circle;
class Rect;

class Shape {
public:
   enum Type
   {
      CircleType, RectType, UnknownType
   };

   Shape(Type t)
      : type_m(t)
   {}

   virtual ~Shape() {} // don't forget to declare it virtual!!
   bool intersect(Shape &a);
private:
   Type type_m;
};

bool Circle2Circle(const Shape& circle1, const Shape& circle2);
bool Circle2Rect(const Shape& circle, const Shape& rect);
bool Rect2Rect(const Shape& rect1, const Shape& rect2);

std::function<bool(const Shape&, const Shape&)> intersectFuncTable[Shape::UnknownType][Shape::UnknownType] =
{ 
   { Circle2Circle, Circle2Rect },
   { Circle2Rect, Rect2Rect }
};

bool Shape::intersect(Shape &a)
{
   return intersectFuncTable[type_m][a.type_m](*this, a);
}

class Circle : public Shape {
public:
   Circle() 
      : Shape(CircleType)
   {}
};

bool Circle2Circle(const Shape& circle1, const Shape& circle2)
{
   if (dynamic_cast<const Circle*>(&circle1) == nullptr ||
      (dynamic_cast<const Circle*>(&circle2)) == nullptr)
      return false;
   cout << "circle to circle\n";
  return true;
};

class Rect : public Shape {
public:
   Rect() 
      : Shape(RectType)  
   {}
};

bool Circle2Rect(const Shape& shape1, const Shape& shape2)
{
   if (dynamic_cast<const Circle*>(&shape1) != nullptr && dynamic_cast<const Rect*>(&shape2) != nullptr ||
      dynamic_cast<const Rect *>(&shape1) != nullptr && dynamic_cast<const Circle*>(&shape2) != nullptr)
   {
      cout << "circle to rect\n";
      return true;
   }
   return false;
};

bool Rect2Rect(const Shape& rect1, const Shape& rect2)
{
   if (dynamic_cast<const Rect*>(&rect1) == nullptr|| dynamic_cast<const Rect*>(&rect2) == nullptr)
      return false;
   cout << "rect to rect\n";
   return true;
}

int main()
{
   Circle cir;
   Rect rect;

   cir.intersect(rect);
   rect.intersect(cir);
   cir.intersect(cir);
   rect.intersect(rect);

   return 0;
}
```

And The idea is that you implement each of the intersect functions and when adding new types you add a type to the enum in your base class and also add the intersect functions needed. 
Also - On second thought - better to use the type_m and not the dynamic cast because it is less expensive to access a data member.